# Comparison after Typecasting

Tags: java, hibernate, csv, casting, compare

I have a list which is fetched from database using hibernate.

```
List<Object[]> tuples = query.list();
for(Object[] tuple : tuples) {
  myObj temp = new myObj();
  temp.setID(((BigInteger)tuple[1]).longValue());
  temp.setPIndex((Integer)tuple[2]);
  temp.setFIndex((Integer)tuple[3]);
  temp.setSIndex((Integer)tuple[5]);
  temp.setLat(((BigDecimal)tuple[6]));
  temp.setLongt((BigDecimal)(tuple[7]));
  temp.setAlt((BigDecimal)(tuple[8]));
  List.add(temp);
}
```

Where ID is Long, Pindex, FIndex, Sindex are Integer, and Lat, Longt and Alt is Big Decimal.

on the other hand i am having csv files which have data corresponding to these database. I am importing the data from csv files one by one and comparing it with my list but somehow my compare function is not working as excepted.

```
private boolean checkData(List<MyObject> list,MyObject1  map){

    if (list.size() == 0){
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++){
        MyObject temp = (MyObject)list.get(i);

        if (temp.getAlt().compareTo(map.getType2().getAlt())== 0 && temp.getLat().compareTo(map.getType2().getLat()) == 0 && temp.getLongt().compareTo(map.getType2().getLongt()) == 0 && Integer.valueOf(temp.getPIndex()) == Integer.valueOf(map.getType2().getPIndex())&&  Integer.valueOf(temp.getSIndex()) == Integer.valueOf(map.getType2().getSIndex()) && temp.getID().compareTo(map.getCommonTypeData().getID())== 0 && Integer.valueOf(temp.getFIndex()) == Integer.valueOf(map.getType2().getFIndex())){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I don't have any idea why it is working fine for some entries, while not working for others.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Integer comparision to use equals() function. i.e. integer1.equals(integer2).  You are comparing 2 Integer objects using == .  When doing so, java checks to see if the objects are equal.  Whereas, with the equals() method, it checks to see if their values are equal

i.e.

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = new Integer(5);

a.equals(b) will be true
a == b will return false
```

Hope this helps